# Why are laptop/smarthpone chargers not smarter while MCs are dirt cheap and the demand is there?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

<sub>This question might be a better fit for superuser.SE</sub>

Assumptions:

- some microcontrollers are dirt cheap
- Lithium-Ion batteries love being charged to to 50-60% of maximum (== degrade the slowest)
- there exist various rules of thumb about maximum charging current but none about minimum
- Fast Charging is a thing and people need it

Question:
Why don't smartphone/laptop/all_others chargers ask the user what mode of operation do they require? At the higher end I can imagine voice recognition and soft reasoning. At the lower end there's a 3-state selector switch: (fast, normal, tickle). The demand is there, why does the device not exist?

Comment: The fact that you would like such a feature doesn't really mean that 'the demand is there'. It's not.

Comment: what you call `chargers` are not chargers at all ... they are `power supplies` ... the chargers are built into the cell phones and into the laptops ... there is no reason to have the power supplies "smart"

Comment: The charger is actually in the phone. The thing that plugs into the wall does no charging or battery management. It just turns the high voltage AC into low voltage DC so the phone doesn't have to. Now ask yourself: How many features do people want that smartphone manufacturers just don't do? A lot. I would like a feature to stop charging at 70-80% but it is in the manufacturer's best interest that my phone wears out fast

Comment: Every laptop I've ever used has had a BIOS setting to make it not charge the battery above a certain state of charge.

Comment: Why do you think that "The demand is there"?  99% of people want the fastest charge all the time.

Comment: Phones are planned obsolescence devices , they want you to keep replacing batteries or phones, not live for 5x longer .  Yet Lenovo does has this feature of not always charging to maximum to extend the reliability on laptop batteries. 66% is about ideal and are shipped at this state.  A tickle charge to match load and Maint this on charger  essentially keeps the battery in storage state for long life when using a laptop on charger at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Some microcontrollers are dirt cheep

Chips that are cheap are partly cheap because they are produced in huge volume.  Chips designed and mass produced specifically to charge a battery are cheaper because they are simpler, can do as good a job or better with lower power consumption and overhead(they can include anything including programmability or some processing capability similar to a microcontroller), and may be less susceptible to corruption.  Microcontrollers or computers in general process things one at a time in rapid succession, whereas a dedicated circuit can be designed to accomplish tasks in parallel, although it's worth noting that I don't thing battery charging is "real time" enough for this to be a factor.

The energy cost of the extra processing power can be mitigated more easily with a large battery bank where total losses are higher, and as a result the larger the battery bank, the more likely you are to see a more intelligent charger.  I see there's already an answer pointing out electric vehicles.  The EV already has significant processing power, so I would imagine for their charging system they would still use dedicated charging chips rather than a microcontroller, and simply have these controlled by the vehicle's own CPU.

> Lithium-Ion batteries love being charged to to 50-60% of maximum (==
> degrade the slowest)

This is just one factor in a cost/weight/longevity issue.  Many devices actually are designed to maximise battery life this way, but by nature they have to cost more and weigh more because of increased battery mass to achieve the same capacity, and even if you're mass producing a control chip and it's cheaper than a microcontroller, there will be a cost to that extra capability.

> there exist various rules of thumb about maximum charging current but
> none about minimum

I think it's natural that this is a little examined use case.  The only reason I can think of to charge at an arbitrarily small current is because that is all the power available, like in a low power energy recovery unit.

> FastCharg-ing is a thing and people need it

I would argue that it is not needed, it's just a feature that makes use more convenient.  "Fast charging" as it is exists partly because the battery technology existed to efficiently charge lithium ion at higher power levels that would be possible at 5V and 2A.  It would be impractical to require thick unique cables for devices you wanted to charge faster but those same cables can handle more than 5V without problem.  The best solution to increase power delivery within the reasonable range is to negotiate an increase in voltage, which is what a "fast charge" mode does.  As mentioned in the comments, the actual charger is in the phone, and the chargers in phones are an example of the kind of highly capable charger chip you're asking about.  They intelligently negotiate input voltage, are extremely efficient and compact, and are designed to charge the battery within some optimal range to maximise the number of cycles the battery can endure.  Rather than having the unneeded overhead and bulk of a general purpose microcontroller, they simply calculate how "intelligent" the chip has to be to maximize *cost effect* and design a chip to do exactly that.  For a company like Apple, the other "advantage" they get at the expense of the consumer is they can mass produce chips at extremely low cost for their own use and simply not sell them to anyone else, making their device difficult or impossible to repair, giving them the option of gouging the customer on in house repairs or simply forcing the customer to buy a whole new device.

> Question: Why don't smartphone/laptop/all_others chargers ask the user
> what mode of operation do they require?

The most obvious reason I see is that it would be rare that a person could make better(and importantly *more timely*) decisions of this nature than a processor can.  It would be a rare use case to have your phone at 60% battery, plug it in and not want it to be ready as soon as possible.  They would have to spend time and money engineering this capability just to add a limited amount of life time for a ~2 year battery for only a small portion of their market, and it's worth noting they'd rather you buy a new phone in 2 years anyway.

> At the higher end I can
> imagine voice recognition and soft reasoning. At the lower end there's
> a 3-state selector switch: (fast, normal, tickle). The demand is
> there, why does the device not exist?

Voice recognition is a good example of something that would constantly waste power(always listening) and require a significant amount of processor/memory overhead, as well as creating additional failure points.  It would also incur significant *completely unnecessary* engineering and design costs to please a very small number of customers.  When you look at those customers as well, if they actually want slow charge for some reason, there is no motivation for them to pay extra for a higher than normal quality device when they can simply buy an obsolete charger at bargain prices to achieve the same goal.  I argue that the demand is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Lenovo has this algorithm for planned efficient usage @ 60% SoC.
[image]

[Ref](https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/solutions/ht103159-battery-charge-stops-at-60-plugged-in-not-charging-windows-ideapad)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious point is **cost**

There is always a price point and manufacturers are designing for a combination of factors.

The company accountants will always go for the cheapest options for the mass market.

Quality always costs and most are prepared to pay less and replace more often.